# UIview inside another uiview switch with a new

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I have an uiview inside another. I have a button on my subview (i have connect my subview with the iboutlet uiview i have created) and when i tap it i want a new view to be visible in its place. I use this code but i see white blank when i tap it!

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:mysubview cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:view1.view cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.5];
[UIView commitAnimations];

mysubview.hidden = YES;
newview1.view.hidden = NO;
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it after many hours!

Here is the code:

//get currentview

UIView *currentView =mysubview;

```
// hide the previous view
[currentView setHidden:TRUE];
```

//initialize next view

```
MyMessages *view1=[[MyMessages alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMessages" bundle:nil];

[currentView addSubview:view1.view];//add next view to current
[currentView setHidden:FALSE];//show current (actually it should be the next view because we added as a subview)
// set up an animation for the transition between the views
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];//show up the new view from right side (this type of effect happens in navigationcontrollers)
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
//
[[currentView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent view should be able to switch out it's child views using:

```
transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:
```

Creates a transition animation between the specified views using the given parameters.

```
+ (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:     (NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion

Comment: nothing happens!    [UIView transitionFromView:mysubview
                        toView:view1.view
                      duration:0.5 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft   
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        /* do something on animation completion */
                    }];

Comment: Are you sure the view you're animating to and from are valid?  Are they nil?  How are you creating and instantiating those views? UINib?

Comment: I created a project with an uiviewcontroller from xcode. Then i added from the interface builder a new uiview inside the one of my project. I connect the subview to the iboutlet uiview *subview i created in code. I synthesize it. Then i initialize the subview like this  in my viewdidload of my project mysubview=[[UIView alloc]init ]; The one i want to replace i used it in another transition and it works but something wrong with my subview i think but i do not know what is it! Does it sound right by what i am saying regarding my subview?